# Why is 1===1===1 false?

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean-logic

In a browser console, entering `1===1` evaluates to `true`. Entering `1===1===1` evaluates to `false`.

I assume that this is because of the way the statement is evaluated:

`1 === 1 === 1`

becomes

`(1 === 1) === 1`

which evaluates to

`true === 1`

which is `false`.

Is this correct? If not, what's the real reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Actually the operation is parsed left to right. So `1 === 1 === 1` is evaluated as `(1 === 1) === 1`, not `1 === (1 === 1)`. In this case obviously it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the answer to reflect this :)

Comment: Thanks for all the informative answers. I suspected that this was the reasoning, but it's good to get some confirmation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, you're exactly right. Here you have two equality checks, which have the same operator precedence. First one evaluates first, then its result applies to the next equality check.

`1===1===1`is the same as `(1===1)===1` which is `true===1` which is `false`, because here you check by values AND their types. `1==1==1` will result in `true`, because it checks equality by values only, so `1==1==1` equal to `(1==1)==1` equal to `true==1` equal to `true`.

Answer (score 20):

The `===` operator doesn't just test equality, but also type equality.  Since an integer is not a boolean, `true === 1` is false.

Compare:

```javascript
true == 1; // true
true === 1; // false
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8kTB7/).

Comment: It's `true === 1` because the equality operators are left-associative. `true === 1 === 1 // false` while `1 === 1 === true // true`

Comment: @Tibos: Correct, though that doesn't change the point of the answer.  `true == 1` is still true, and `true === 1` is still false.

Comment: Yes, the answer's content is entirely accurate, but in relation to the question it is misleading. Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 3):

Correct behaviour. Since

```
1===1 // value is true
```

but

```
true===1 // it's false
```

There are two reasons for this:

1. true is a boolean type where 1 is integer
2. simply, 1 is not equal to true.

so

```
1===1===1 // false
```

Comment: Point 2) depends on the browser implementation. In C for example, there is no 'Boolean', instead ints are used, with 0 as false and anything else as true, so 1 would indeed equal 'true'. Hence `1==true`. **tl;dr** the only difference between 1 and true is the type in some implementations.

Comment: @11684 - It does _not_ depend on browser implementation. It depends on correct implementation of the spec. This is JavaScript, not C, and `boolean` is not numeric (even though according to the spec there can be type coercion if the `==` operator were being used instead of `===`).

Comment: In C there is no boolean type and often ints are used as 0 evaluates to false automatically and any other int value to true. JavaScript is mostly interpreted, so such a comparison will be executed by the browser natively.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that you mentioned is correct.

Its because `===` implies matching based on type and value. 
`true === 1` does not match on type, but `true == 1` matches based on value.

Comment: It's `true === 1` because the equality operators are left-associative.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I know its left-associative :)

Comment: You could edit your answer to improve it (or delete if you don't think you can add value to a potential future reader).

Answer (score -2):

if 1==1==1 then it will be true

Comment: ==will change the arg type and === will not